# React saving rate in state and localStorage

Tags: reactjs

I  have some trouble with my code. I made an app where I use an API `last fm` and I want to add a rating button, I get few things from Google. Rating is displayed where I want to be, I can console log him, but it's on external file and I have no idea how to modify `rate` state from my `app.js`. Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { getArtists } from './services/api';


import {
  TextField,
  Button,
  List
} from '@material-ui/core';

import { ArtistCard } from './components/ArtistCard';
import { SearchResult } from './components/SearchResult';

import './App.css';
import { get } from 'https';

const handleChangeRate = (state) => {
  this.setState({rate: state})
}
const isEmpty = (str) => str.length === 0;
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: '',
    savedArtists: [],
    rate:[]
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const existing = localStorage.getItem('savedArtists')
    if (existing) {
      this.setState({ savedArtists: JSON.parse(existing) })
    }
  }

  onTextChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({ searchTerm: value });
  }

  search = async (terms) => {

    const artists = await getArtists(terms);
    this.setState({ artists: artists })
  }

  onSearchClick = () => {
    this.search(this.state.searchTerm);
  }

  clearSearch = () => {
    this.setState({
      searchTerm: '',
      artists: []
    })
  }

  updateArtists = (newArtists) => {
    this.setState({ savedArtists: newArtists })
    localStorage.setItem('savedArtists', JSON.stringify(newArtists));
  }

  deleteArtist = (artist) => {
    const result = this.state.savedArtists.filter(item => item.name !== artist.name);
    this.updateArtists(result);
  }

  onResultClick = (artist) => {
    this.clearSearch();
    const savedArtists = this.state.savedArtists;
    savedArtists.push(artist);
    this.updateArtists(savedArtists);
  }

   handleChangeRate = (state) => {
    this.setState({rate: state})
  }

  render() {
    const results = this.state.artists || [];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <AppBar position="static" color="primary">
            <Toolbar className="search-bar">
              <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
                Photos
              </Typography>
              <TextField
                placeholder="Search on Last.fm"
                className="search-input"
                onChange={this.onTextChange}
                value={this.state.searchTerm}
              />
              <Button
                onClick={this.onSearchClick}
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                disabled={isEmpty(this.state.searchTerm)}
              >
                Search
              </Button>
              {!isEmpty(this.state.searchTerm) && (
                <Button
                  onClick={this.clearSearch}
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Clear
                </Button>)
              }
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </header>

        <List className="search-results">
          {
            results.map((artist, index) => {
              return <SearchResult key={index} artist={artist} onResultClick={this.onResultClick} />
            })
          }
        </List>
        <div className="artist-container">
          {
            this.state.savedArtists.map((artist, index) => {
              return <ArtistCard artist={artist} key={index} deleteArtist={this.deleteArtist} onChangeRating={this.handleChangeRate}  /> 
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

artistCard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardContent, CardActions, Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import ReactStars from 'react-stars'


export const ratingChanged = (newRating) => {
  const { onChangeRating } = this.props;
  onChangeRating(newRating);
}
export const ArtistCard = (props) => {
  const { artist, deleteArtist } = props;
  console.log(artist.cardImage)

  return (
    <Card className="artist-card">
      <div className="image-container">
        <img src={artist.cardImage} alt={artist.name} />
      </div>
      <CardContent>
        <h3>{artist.name}</h3>
        <p>{artist.listeners} listeners.</p>

    <ReactStars
    count = {5}
    onChange={ratingChanged}
    size={27}
    color2 ={'#ffd700'}
    />

      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Share
      </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="secondary" onClick={() => deleteArtist(artist)}>
          Delete
      </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Comment: Alphabet 'R' should not be capital in state `Rate`(Just suggesting change not saying that error is due to that)

Comment: Hi Adu, can you please clarify what do you mean by external file? I can see that you are already doing something with `deleteArtist`, can you not change the rating as an attribute of your `artist` data structure?

Comment: I need to save the rating value (1,1.5,2 etc) in state "rate". But idk how to do it properly . i  console.log it , but i have trouble saving that in state. @ Sumanth Madishetty  i already corect that .

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty To the best of my knowledge that is just a naming convention and nothing to do with the problem OP is asking for. Does it behave differently when you call it rate or Rate or rAtE ?

Comment: @dubes I dint mention that the error is due to that. I just suggested that change, To be clear I will edit my previous comment

Comment: @AduAdrian it should be very similar to how you are storing and modifying `savedArtists` in your state. But I am assuming that you need to lookup the Rating by artist id, so perhaps it is best to keep the rating inside your savedArtists json. However, your question seems to be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO, you can try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or the reactJS [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs) for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the function to change State to  artistCard as props

In `App.js` add the following fucntion

```
const handleChangeRate = (state) => {
  this.setState(rate: state)
}
```

and Pass the same as props to ArtistCard like specified

```
<ArtistCard artist={artist} key={index} deleteArtist={this.deleteArtist} onChangeRating={this.handleChangeRate}  />
```

And in artistCard.js change ratingChanged method to

```
  const ratingChanged = (newRating) => {
  const { onChangeRating } = this.props;
  onChangeRatng(newRating);
}
```

PS: This answer is based on the understanding i gained after going through this question, If this is not the requirement Please feel free to comment

**EDIT**

```
const handleChangeRate = (state) => {
  this.setState(rate: state)
}
```

try adding the value prop to ReactStart like specified below

```
<ReactStars
  value={this.props.rate}
  count={5}
  onChange={ratingChanged}
  size={24}
  color2={'#ffd700'}
/>
```

Pass rate state to artist card component as prop like specified below

```
<ArtistCard artist={artist} key={index} deleteArtist= {this.deleteArtist} onChangeRating={this.handleChangeRate} rate={this.state.rate} />
```

**EDIT**
cardComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactStars from 'react-stars'


export const ArtistCard = (props) => {
const { artist, deleteArtist, onChangeRating } = props;
console.log(props.rating)
return (
 <ReactStars
   value={props.rating}
   count = {5}
   onChange={(newRating) => onChangeRating(newRating)}
   size={27}
   color2 ={'#ffd700'}
 />)}
```

App.js

```
  handleChangeRate = (state) => {
   this.setState({rate: state})
  }

<ArtistCard artist={'artist'} key={'index'} rating={this.state.rate} deleteArtist={this.deleteArtist} onChangeRating={this.handleChangeRate}  />
```

**FINAL EDIT**

Changes made in your code

App.js

modified state object to

```
state = {
  searchTerm: '',
  savedArtists: [],
  rate: ''
}
```

Artistcard component line to

```
<ArtistCard rate={this.state.rate} artist={artist} key={index} onChangeRating={(val) => {this.setState({ rate: val })}} deleteArtist={this.deleteArtist} />
```

In ArtistCard.js

rendering reactstart component like this

```
<ReactStars
   value={props.rate}
   count = {5}
   onChange={(newRating) => onChangeRating(newRating)}
   size={27}
   color2 ={'#ffd700'}
 />
```

Comment: I have made a small mistake in `handleChangeRate` method please check the updated answer

Comment: this time did not crush , but still don't update my state ' rate'

Comment: can you post your updated code && try console logging the state in render method of App.js

Comment: @AduAdrian, Thank you can you try sending value as prop to artistcard component as specified in my latest edit

Comment: @ Sumanth Madishetty "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" . I wanted to add those numbers after, making an average.

Comment: remove this from this.props.rate

Comment: can you share any reproducable repo

Comment: @AduAdrian I haven't tried cloning your repo but i have implemented similar code as your and got it working

Comment: Strange, mine crashes when i try to rate .. ty anyway mate .

Comment: @AduAdrian I have Updated my answer now with the updated implementation please find that

Comment: Please find the source code for the same in this repo https://github.com/sumanthmadishetty/create-react-app-boilerplate/tree/react-stars

Comment: If you are reffering to that repo please find that branch name is react-stars

Comment: I got React starts to working with your repo If you need i can post the changes i made

Comment: updated changes made in your code to make react stars working

Comment: Ty dude  ! i rlly apreciate this !

Comment: All the best ...!